# What are the origins of the 「こそあど」 demonstratives?

Tags: etymology, demonstratives

I've noticed the following sets of words that seem to have a very obvious pattern, and, of course, their meanings are very closely related:

- これ、　それ、　あれ、　どれ
- この、　その、　あの、　どの
- ここ、　そこ、　あそこ、　どこ

What are the origins of these sets of words? I'm asking them all together because I'm thinking that their origin is interrelated.

Comment: こっち、そっち、あっち、どっち, こなた、そなた、あなた、どなた, and more.

Comment: My favorite set of this type is こいつ, そいつ, あいつ. Haven't seen どいつ yet though!

Comment: @sartak I usually only see it in the phrase どいつもこいつも.

Comment: Forgetting こう、そう、ああ、どう??  I've personally never (or maybe once) heard anyone use 「ああ」.

Comment: @istrasci I see ああ a lot with いう, like ああいう人 ("a person like that")

Comment: @Amanda, @Makdad - Is it a regional thing???  Never heard that living in Osaka.

Comment: @istrasci It's pretty normal in Tokyo, for what that's worth. Maybe Osakans have a different saying instead?

Comment: @sartak I sometimes hear 「これやらかしたのはどこのどいつだ！！」which I may, not reading the 空気, accidentally reply with 「ヨーロッパのドイツ」

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you use the kanjis, you see the pattern even better!

此れ、 其れ、 彼、  何れ

此の、 其の、 彼の、 何の

此処、 其処、 彼処、 何処

From there, the suffixes "れ"、 "の"、 and "こ" indicate whether you're talking about a thing, a "possessive", or a location.
The prefixes are, as you had guessed, the "distance": close, somehow far, far, and the question "which".

So, "これ" is the close thing, そのX is "the X of mildly far away" and "どこ" is "which location?".
Understanding the others is then straightforward.

Comment: Ah!  That must be where 彼（かれ）comes from as well.

Comment: @Troyen cool, i was thinking how there may be a relation. but it seems like there's no relation at all.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is about origins.